# Randomly extract a number of consecutive items from a sequence in R

Tags: r, sequence

```
Frag <- seq(1: 30000)
K <- 9
P <- sample(1:K,1)
sys.sample <- Frag[seq(P, length(Frag), K)]
```

Now sys.sample contains 3333 numbers. How do I randomly extract 16 consecutive items in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a vector `v` has `n` elements and you want to randomly extract `p` consecutive elements (`p<=n`), you can do:

```
possibleIndex = seq(length(v) - p + 1)
firstIndex = sample(possibleIndex, 1)

v[firstIndex:(firstIndex + p -1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But when I rerun the code, I get different numbers of elements. How come?

Comment: becuase `sample` takes each time a different initial index :) ! You can add `set.seed()` to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Putting @ColonelBeauvel's answer into a function would look like this

```
extractRandWindow <- function(x, p){
    firstIndex = sample(seq(length(x) - p + 1), 1)
    x[firstIndex:(firstIndex + p -1)]
}
```

[image]