# Randomly extract a series of consecutive numbers from a sequence

Tags: r, string, subset, sequence

Using R, I am currently trying to randomly extract (different starting points) a series of 5 consecutive integers. I tried the function provided in the answer here - [Randomly extract a number of consecutive items from a sequence in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945338/randomly-extract-a-number-of-consecutive-items-from-a-sequence-in-r), but I keep running into this error

```
# function used to subset a randomly chosen set of 5 integers
extractRandWindow <- function(x, p){
  firstIndex = sample(seq(length(x) - p + 1), 1)
  x[firstIndex:(firstIndex + p -1)]
}

# below files corresponds to a vector containing a series of integers

subset <- extractRandWindow(files,5)

# I keep getting this error below

Error in x[firstIndex:(firstIndex + p - 1)] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Based on @Gregor Thomas' suggestion, here's the class and structure of the strings:

```
> dput(files)
c("D:\\2020-summer\\HP36P1B\\HP36P1B_20200304_160000.WAV", "D:\\2020-summer\\HP36P1B\\HP36P1B_20200304_160500.WAV", 
"D:\\2020-summer\\HP36P1B\\HP36P1B_20200304_161000.WAV", "D:\\2020-summer\\HP36P1B\\HP36P1B_20200304_161500.WAV")
```

Any solutions? I realized my dput has <number of elements requested. That's the cause of the error.

Comment: It seems like the issue is with your `files` object, so please share it reproducibly. `dput(files[1:20])` should give a copy/pasteable version of the first 20 elements of `files` with all class and structure information included.

Comment: For example, if I set `foo = 1:100`, then `extractRandWindow(foo, 5)` seems to work just fine. So you need to help us understand what's different about your `files` object.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas - technically, they are file names and I am trying to essentially randomly select a consecutive sequence of 5 files. The principle like you said should work, as you described above for just integers, but I seem to get an error with the above strings

Comment: Made the changes you requested @GregorThomas

Comment: Your code works for me.  I can't duplicate the error.

Comment: I set `files <-` your `dput` results, and `extractRandWindow(files 5)` works fine for me.

Comment: You've got less than 5 elements. So `length(x) - p + 1` could be 0. Why not set `p <- min(p, length(x))`?